# Open an accordion with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to open an accordion link with selenium in python.

The element looks like this when closed:

```
<div class="crm-accordion-body" style="display: none;">
```

and this when open:

```
<div class="crm-accordion-body" style="display: block;">
```

The code I'm trying to use to change the style is:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('crm-accordion-body').style.display = 'block';")
```

This produces the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `document.getElementsByClassName('crm-accordion-body')` returns a Node List. So we have to use index to get hold of the intended Node as follows :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-pageMenu')[0].style.display
```

So as we are trying to change the `style="display: none;"` for the first node, try the following line of code :

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('crm-accordion-body')[0].style.display='block';")
```

Comment: I get the same result without the spaces unfortunately.

Comment: Updated the Answer. Update the status please.

Comment: That works with one small change. I had to change the index to 2 for some reason. Thanks! `driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('crm-accordion-body')[2].style.display='block';")`

Comment: @BrianKeats Upvote the answer if this/any Answer is helping to you.