# Python selenium webdriver expanding accordion-container (take two)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, accordion

I have been building a scraper which works well but requires me to manually expand the hidden data before it can successfully scrape it. I have checked the webpage source code and the data lies in 3x different accordion containers.

There is a table header banner which is clickable and contains a number of header elements that are also **scraped**. I have tried every possible xpath within the header that may contain the clickable element along with code like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="income-statement-accordion"]/thead/tr/th[1]').click
```

but no possible xpath combination expands the table.
When I look at the source code, the only bit of source code that appears to change when I click the header is as follows

```
<table _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c34="" class="full-width income-statement swipable-table accordion-container" id="income-statement-accordion"> == $0
```

changes to this (I'm not sure the importance of `== $0`?):

```
<table _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c34="" class="full-width income-statement swipable-table accordion-container active-accordion" id="income-statement-accordion">
```

I have viewed a similar question here: [Open an accordion with selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115719/open-an-accordion-with-selenium-in-python). However, attempting a similar take on this does not do anything, although does admittedly submit without error and returns `none`:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('income-statement-accordion').class='full-width income-statement swipable-table accordion-container active-accordion';")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to post the website you're trying to scrape?

Comment: yes it is: https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/EZJ/easyjet-plc/fundamentals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'accordion-toggler')]")
for element in elements:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

This will expand *all* accordion sections.

If you just want to target individual sections

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='income-statement-accordion']//span[contains(@class, 'accordion-toggler')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

We need to use javascript to click the elements because selenium does not classify them as "interactable".